# Wcf configuration for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf

In my silverlight app I use service reference to wcf service.  After I deployed this project to my test IIS, I couldn't see any .config file where all endpoint information is stored.  That ServiceReferences.ClientConfig is packed in xap package.  How would I deploy it to customer's server then?  I need a way to configure endpoint there.  How do you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to support editing the clientconfig file in the XAP, here is another approach.

Add the web service endpoint address to the Silverlight InitParams in the HTML page that host the Silverlight application. Maybe set the initparams dynamically via ASP.NET. Programatically use this address when creating the client-side service proxy.

Another option is to assume the web service is always in a relative directory to the hosting page. I used something like:

```
new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, new Uri("./MyService/MyService.svc", UriKind.Relative));
```

Combining both options works well, if the InitParams are missing, I use a the relative path to the well known location (helpful in deployment/production). If the IntiParams have a endpoint, I use that (helpful in debugging/testing).

Answer (score 3):

If you mean configure the endpoint after the application has been published then there is no  way to do it easily (you could unzip the xap, change the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig, rezip ...)

Comment: @Nickolodeon, I understand your point but one of the goals of xap files is to package and application and all its dependencies. Moving configuration files out of it prevents the single file goal. In my SL apps, I usually use build events to copy the appropriate service conf file depending on the configuration (dev, test, prod...)

Comment: I'll try InitParams approach.  But when all fails, modifying xap is the way to go - I tried it and it works)